# Relation between energy and power

Tags: energy

The kinetic energy of a 1 ton car moving at 65mph is computed as
$$
KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(901kg\right)\left(29ms^{-1}\right)^{2}=380,000J
$$
We know that power is the rate at which energy is used or generated,
and that $1W=1Js^{-1}$. So, from the above example, is the power
of this car moving at 65mph 380,000 Watts? What does this even mean?
Joules already take into account time by dividing by $s^{2},$don't
they? Intuitively, to me, I would think that:
$$
KE=\int_{t_{0}}^{t1}Power\text{dt}
$$

In other words, the total amount of power generated (summed over time) would yield total energy. But, if 1W=1J/s, then why is time even relevant? In other words, the power seems to simply be the total energy per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The Kinetic Energy of the car is a fixed value of Joules that you calculated.  If the car moving at that speed had no friction (say in space) no power input would be needed to maintain that speed.

A number unrelated (mostly) to the kinetic energy is the power expended by the engine to keep it moving against air friction and surface friction. The energy balance of the car in this case looks like:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}E_{total} =   \frac{d}{dt}E_{kinetic} = -P_{friction}+P_{engine}
$$

For a car running at constant speed, the $dE_{total}$ term is zero, the $dE_{kinetic}$ term is zero, and the two power terms must be equal:

$$ P_{friction}=P_{engine}$$

You can see that the $P$ terms do not even need to be the same order of magnitude as the kinetic energy. The engine could be expending 10 kW = 10 kJ per sec to maintain a kinetic energy of 380 kJ.  It is apples and oranges.